# Docker and Gradle won't use dependencies cache

Tags: docker, gradle

I've been trying to build a Docker container that will run my Android CI pipeline (most of it at least) on Github Actions, the problem is: my company has several private dependencies.

So I have created a Docker image that run the steps online while connected to my company network and everything runs fine. Then I commit that Docker image, create a new tag and upload it to a registry... however, whenever I'm in another PC and try running Gradle offline, it just won't work... Even though it has the dependencies cached.

Is there any other way of achieving what I'm trying here? I don't think volumes work with Github Actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happens that I had a configuration preventing Gradle from storing its dependencies.

```
buildCache {
    local {
        enabled = false
    }
}
```

After enabling that and running Gradle once again I was able to get things working properly. My steps were:

1. Creating a Docker image from scratch
2. Running the build steps while online and connected to my company network
3. Commit that image and then upload it to DockerHub

I've decided to commit the image instead of copying my host Gradle dependencies to the image because in previous testings it was having some issues regarding OS specific deps. This way it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could think about downloading your dependencies once and afterward copy the directory where they are stored ($GRADLE_USER_HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2) and invoke that directory into your offline setup.

To do so, before/alongside executing your Gradle (offline) command, simply set the GRADLE_RO_DEP_CACHE variable as a read-only dependency cache point to that directory. For further information please see the Gradle documentation at:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html#sub:shared-readonly-cache

Comment: Thanks for that, happens that I had a configuration preventing gradle from saving the .jars after running a build... All my fault